# How do I prove that $A\subseteq B \Leftrightarrow W-B \subseteq W-A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am writing a proof to another statement and this Lemma is missing in order to be complete.

How do I prove this formally?

$$(A\subseteq B) \Longleftrightarrow (W-B \subseteq W-A)$$

Comment: What are $A,B$ and $W$? what have you tried? what don't you understand?

Comment: every x in A is also in B. I would like to say in a formal way that if x in W and not in B, x is also in W and not in A

Comment: oh, can I say that if x is in W and not in B it means that if it was in W and in A it would contradict the A is in B/

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer You need more restrictions this isn't true, for instance if $W=\varnothing$. There must be a premise that $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $W$ which you forgot to mention.

Comment: How is it similar to this:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775218/prove-that-if-a-subseteq-b-then-b-subseteq-a
?

Comment: @GitGud - if $W=\emptyset$ then $W-B=\emptyset\subseteq\emptyset=W-A$.

Comment: @SuzuHirose So, the RHS of $\iff$ is true while $A\subseteq B$ isn't necessarily so.

Comment: @GitGud - I see your point now.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed biconditional holds provided both $A$ and $B$ are *subsets* of $W$.

---

$\Rightarrow $ Assume $A\subseteq B$. Then if $x \in A,$ it follows that $x \in B$. That is, $$\forall x(x\in A \rightarrow x\in B)$$

- Now prove, from this assumption, it follows that $\forall x(x \in W-B \rightarrow x \in W-A)$, and so $(A\subseteq B) \implies (W-B \subseteq W-A)$

---

$\Leftarrow$ Assume $W-B\subseteq W-A$. So, if $x \in W-B$, then $x \in W-A$. That is $$x\in W-B \rightarrow x\in W-A$$

- Now prove that from this assumption, it follows that if $x \in A$,
  then $x \in B$. That is, $(W-B \subseteq W-A) \implies (A \subseteq B)$.

---

**HINT:** $$\forall x(x \in A \rightarrow x \in B) \equiv \forall x( x \notin B \rightarrow x \notin A)$$

Comment: the "now prove" part is ok with what i wrote on the comment to the main post?
i.e: oh, can I say that if x is in W and not in B it means that if it was in W and in A it would contradict the A is in B/